# Change Wakfu installation folder

Tags: steam, wakfu

here's my problem : 
When I launch Wakfu from Steam, it installs some files on my first HD (in the Appdata\Local folder) but there is no more space left in it (all my steam games (even Wakfu) are installed on my second HD) so it won't install the game completely. 
My question is : how can I change the default folder of the in-game installation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would be better off on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com), **however**, it looks like it has [already been asked](http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/) *and [answered](http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition/6395#6395)*.

Comment: Thank you. Junctions were just what I needed (I've never heard of them before now).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Wait, what?  Installing a game onto a different drive isn't something we help with?  This sounds exactly like something we do.

Comment: Determining installation drive is fine. But relocating additional resources placed in %appdata% or my documents might be more tricky and up superuser's alley. That said, just because there might be more people there able to offer solutions to this issue does not necessarily mean it's off-topic here.